# How to open submenu item in a menu bar item (Through Terminal) - Xcode Macbook

Tags: terminal, xcode, menu-bar

So right now I have...

```
osascript \
    -e 'tell application "System Events" to ¬' \
    -e 'tell process "Xcode" to ¬' \
    -e 'click menu bar item "Product" of menu bar 1'
```

I want to be able to open the submenu item in that menu bar item, but I can't figure it out, and I am trying to do it through Macbook Terminal.

The specififc submenu item is "Run" which is under product on xcode project:

Comment: Do you want to do this visually for the user, or are you just trying to activate Run itself? Does Runalready have a key command? [I can't check, don't have Xcode]

Comment: "Run" does value, and by clicking "Run", it builds the tools that transform your code and resource files into a finished app(Onto iPhone which is in developer mode). The key command is [Command + R].

Comment: So why not, if you have to have it inside a script, use `keystroke "r" using command down`

Comment: Technically speaking, you're *not* doing this through Terminal; you're doing this through AppleScript.  All you're doing is running AppleScript commands from Terminal.  Get it working in AppleScript using the GUI then transpose the commands as you've done in the original question.

Comment: Yeah, but I did figure everything out though! Thank you for the help everybody!